# Grafana + MySql: Calculate Cum Sum over COUNT(*) -- Not Working

Tags: mysql, grafana

This is the query, it works -- no errors. But it retrieves idetnical values as if the cumSum value is always reset to zero!

Tried OVER(PARTITION ...) but it gives sytax error! Replacing COUNT() with Value also gives syntax error.

Any tips?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Value, $__timeGroupAlias(modified,'1M'), (@cumSum := @cumSum + COUNT(*)) as cumSum
FROM      Task CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cumSum := 0) params
WHERE     modified > now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND status NOT LIKE '%completed%' 
GROUP BY  time
ORDER BY  time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tasks.time ,  tasks.c , (@cumSum := @cumSum + tasks.c) as cumSum
FROM (SELECT @cumSum := 0) params  JOIN ( 
SELECT $__timeGroupAlias(modified,'1M')  ,  count(name) as c
FROM tabTask  
WHERE modified > now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND status NOT LIKE '%completed%'
group by time
order by time) as tasks
```